# How to gain access to hosts file in java using FileWriter/BufferedWriter

Tags: java, hosts

I'm making a website blocker by manipulating the hosts file through java(GUI). 
Apparently it tells me that my access is denied. This is my code:

```
FileWriter hostWrite = new FileWriter("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
        BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(hostWrite);
        fw.newLine();
        fw.write("127.0.0.1 "+web1); // web1 is the website entered by the user
```

What should I do? And I've read other answers but they don't seem to tell what the solution is exactly. Some just refer to AccessController but I'm not sure how to use it in my code. Please help :) Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running your program in administrator mode?

Comment: Controlling access to system resources is an *operating system* responsibility.  There is nothing your Java program can do on its own to defeat access denial by the OS -- if there were, it would constitute a critical security flaw in the OS.  Instead, you must work with the operating system's mechanisms to afford access to the needed resources.  Often that means running the application as a privileged user, or as one to whom special access rights have been granted.